# If the cells.value does not contains "*30G*" Then

Tags: excel, vba

I'm facing issue with a condition within a VBA code.

```
If Cells(i, 10).Value = Blank And Cells(i, 26).Value <= 61 _
       And Cells(i, 1).Value <> "*30G*" Then
```

I would like to ignore the row which contains the following string in his cells value (col A). Basically, the Cells(I, 1).Value are ID number. The objective is to send email only for the #ID that does not contains or starting with "30G". Otherwise, the code is running well, I'm stuck with this new constraint.

Answer (score 1):

> If the cells.value does not contains “*30G*” Then

Use **[InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function)**

Is this what you are trying?

```
If Len(Trim(Cells(i, 10).Value)) = 0 And _
   Cells(i, 26).Value <= 61 And _
   InStr(1, Cells(i, 1).Value, "30G", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

End If
```

Comment: Ok let me try this ! Thx